org.apache.avro:avro-compiler generates wrong schema field when using references
I have two schemas, that reference eachother:
Schema A:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "A",
  "namespace": "io.test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "ni",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "doc": "Not important"
    }
  ]
}

Schema B:
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "B",
  "namespace": "io.test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "a1",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "A"
      ],
      "doc": "ref 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "a2",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "A"
      ],
      "doc": "ref 2"
    }
  ]
}

Executing the avro compiler from maven produces a java class that looks something like this:
@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public class B extends org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase implements org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = ...;


  public static final org.apache.avro.Schema SCHEMA$ = new org.apache.avro.Schema.Parser().parse("{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"B\",\"namespace\":\"io.test\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"a1\",\"type\":[\"null\",{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"A\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"ni\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"string\"],\"doc\":\"Not important\"}]}],\"doc\":\"ref 1\"},{\"name\":\"a2\",\"type\":[\"null\",\"A\"],\"doc\":\"ref 2\"}]}");
  public static org.apache.avro.Schema getClassSchema() { return SCHEMA$; }

...

I have a problem with the generated SCHEMA$ variable. The generator includes schama A inside schema B.
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "B",
  "namespace": "io.test",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "a1",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "record",
          "name": "A",
          "fields": [
            {
              "name": "ni",
              "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
              ],
              "doc": "Not important"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "doc": "ref 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "a2",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "A"
      ],
      "doc": "ref 2"
    }
  ]
}

Does anyone know the solution? I would like to set the SCHEMA$ variable to the original schema.

This is a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-2838
